# How to button enable when all textbox has value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am new in programming. Here I have given description of my problem
I have one pair of two text box. One text box is for URL and other is for instruction but all text-boxes created dynamically depending on what value comes from database.

For example `$testing_type_id=2` so I get total two pair of text boxes, let it called bundle. `$i` is used to identify textbox uniquely.

```
  <input type = "text"  size="33"   class="uploadtxt1 url" name="txturl_<?php echo $testing_type_id ; ?>" id = "txturl_<?php echo $testing_type_id; ?>_<?php echo $i ; ?>" value="" />
             <input type = "text"  class="uploadtxt2" size="33" name="txtinstruction_<?php echo $testing_type_id ; ?>" id = "txtinstruction_<?php echo $testing_type_id; ?>_<?php echo $i ; ?>" value=""  /> <br/>
             <input type="submit" name="checkout" id="checkout"   class="graybtn1 ptr  button_float_left_checkout" disabled="disabled" value="Proceed To Checkout" />
```

Here what I wanted to do that if  all bundle has value, either in one textbox or both textbox so and so enable submit button. If I removed value so disable submit button using jQuery.

Comment: Hello nic. I don't mean to be rude or anything. But your English is a bit broken. So this is how I interpret your problem. You want to check to see if your textbox has something in it and then hide a button if it does or doesn't? Is that correct?

Comment: yup something like that. if all pair of text boxes(url or instruction) has value so button enable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this will work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[class^='uploadtxt']").keyup(function(e){
        var alltxt=$("input[class^='uploadtxt']").length;
        var empty=true;
        $("input[class^='uploadtxt']").each(function(i){
            if($(this).val()=='')
            {
                empty=true;
                $('#checkout').prop('disabled', true);
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                empty=false;
            }
        });
        if(!empty)  $('#checkout').prop('disabled', false);                    
    });
});​
```

An example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WQcdq/4/).

Comment: thanks for your help. but in your example if i write anything first in textbox2 so button enable.

Comment: What do you want, you said to check if any textbox is empty then disable the button, if you have more buttons (i.e. 5) then it will be enabled after each button has filled up.

Comment: yes if i write first on textbox2 so textbox1 is empty and button is enable

Comment: thanks but i wanted to know that is it possible to do this using length? given in http://jsfiddle.net/WQcdq/1/

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it what do you want to know !

Comment: can i enable button using                                             var alltxt=$("input[class^='uploadtxt']").length;

Comment: No, it returns the item count.

Comment: actually my real problem is: i have pair of two text box if either one or both has value in all pair of text box so enable button.in your example if both text box has value in all pair so button enable. btw i really appreciate for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('.uploadtxt1').val() !='' && $('.uploadtxt2').val() !='')
{
    $('#checkout').hide();
}
else
{
    $('#checkout').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you want to show/ enable the button if the textareas / inputs have values. You could do something like this using jQuery.

```
$(window).ready(function(){

   if( $('input, textarea').val().length >=0 ){

     //run function to enable button

   }

   else if ( $('input, textarea').val().length <=0 ){

      //run function to disable button

   }

});
```

I think this is what you are sort of looking for. Let me know if I am way off or not understanding you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest a minor markup changes so that will be easy to handle the traversing.

Wrap the elements in a `<div>`

```
<div class="item">
    <input type = "text"  size="33"   class="uploadtxt1 url" name="txturl_<?php echo $testing_type_id ; ?>" id = "txturl_<?php echo $testing_type_id; ?>_<?php echo $i ; ?>" value="" />
    <input type = "text"  class="uploadtxt2" size="33" name="txtinstruction_<?php echo $testing_type_id ; ?>" id = "txtinstruction_<?php echo $testing_type_id; ?>_<?php echo $i ; ?>" value=""  /> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="checkout" id="checkout"   class="graybtn1 ptr  button_float_left_checkout" disabled="disabled" value="Proceed To Checkout" />
</div>
```

Then, Attach a snippet on the `change` event

```
$("input[type=text]", $(".item")).change(function() {
    var allField = true;
    $(this).closest(".item").find("input[type=text]").each(function() {
         allField = allField && ($(this).val().length > 0)
    });
    if(allField) {
        $(this).closest(".item").find("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

#### [Demo of Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/zbAjv/)